# MySQL Timestamps in dual tables (Need to Calculate Percentages)

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sum

I have two tables, let's call them `timeclock`, and `time_tracker`.

Both tables have `timestamps` in, and timestamps out. The time_tracker only creates a "time_in" entry if a worker is actually in a specific application, and then creates a "time_out" entry when they mark their work as complete.

There will be several of these entries in time_tracker in a given day, while there will only be one in, and one out in the timeclock.

I am trying to determine the amount of time worked, versus the amount of time clocked in, and present that as a percentage.

What I have done so far works until I join in the timeclock table. When I do this, it appears that the times are then multiplied somehow, and I can't determine where the fault lies.

Query Below:

```
SELECT it.user_id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, it.time_in, it.time_out) / 60) as `Total Time Clocked In`,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, isb.start_time, isb.end_time) / 60) as `Total Time in Work`
FROM time.time_track isb
INNER JOIN time.timeclock it ON isb.user_id = it.user_id
WHERE it.time_in >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND it.time_out <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
AND isb.start_time >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND isb.end_time <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
AND it.user_id = '12';
```

Comment: I think you need a GROUP BY.

Comment: @Mihai Since the `WHERE` clause restricts it to a single user ID, `GROUP BY` isn't needed.

Comment: The only reason it would be multiplied is if there are multiple matching rows in `timeclock`. You said there should only be one row in `timeclock`, but I suspect you're wrong.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Barmar, you are correct. I didn't account for lunch breaks, which are also another entry in time_in and time_out. Any suggestions on how to go about pulling the timeclock differently?

Comment: Barmar, I haven't previously had any interaction with sqlfiddle; however, I will look at creating some sample data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that your "Total Time Clocked In" is too high this should solve the problem.  Remove the `SUM` function from that expression.

```
SELECT it.user_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, it.time_in, it.time_out) / 60 as `Total Time Clocked In`,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, isb.start_time, isb.end_time) / 60) as `Total Time in Work`
FROM time.time_track isb
INNER JOIN time.timeclock it ON isb.user_id = it.user_id
WHERE it.time_in >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND it.time_out <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
AND isb.start_time >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND isb.end_time <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
AND it.user_id = '12';
```

**EDIT** - I didn't realize there could be multiple records in the timeclock table for a specific day.  The following statement should work in that scenario.

```
SELECT  a.user_id, a.`Total Time Clocked In`, b.`Total Time in Work`

FROM

(
    SELECT  it.user_id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, it.time_in, it.time_out)) / 60 as `Total Time Clocked In`

    FROM    time.timeclock it

    WHERE   it.time_in >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND it.time_out <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
            AND it.user_id = '12'
) AS a

JOIN 

(
    SELECT  isb.user_id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, isb.start_time, isb.end_time) / 60) as `Total Time in Work`

    FROM    time.time_track isb

    WHERE   isb.start_time >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND isb.end_time <= '2013-10-01 23:59:59'
            AND isb.user_id = '12'

) AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Comment: That did fix the timeclock from displaying too high; however, the same is happening with the time_worked field, and removing SUM doesn't help with this field.

Comment: I will mention again, the query breaks only when I add the join. If I do a UNION with a SELECT for each table, it works fine...but then I can't work out the percentage query on the resultsets.

Comment: I just saw your comment about having multiple timeclock recs per day.  That changes things.  This query would need some more tweaking.

Comment: Tom, thanks for the info. Any direction on this one? I just need to find the difference between time worked, and time clocked in for the date range (2013-10-01 00:00:00 to 2013-10-01 23:59:59), then get a percentage for the comparison of time between the two.